# How to fix reverse-matching URL error in Django?

Tags: regex, django, url, django-models, django-views

I'm making a blog app using Django. The error appears when I click on save button on a new post and the 'Post-Detail' page is not just showing up. I'm trying debugging it since last 2 days but still unable to find the solution. I'm using Django(2.1.7) and the error I'm getting is

**NoReverseMatch at /post/new/ Reverse for 'post_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['post/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']`**

There are some other urls as well but I'm just giving the 2 path that most probably creating the errors.

I've tried giving simply redirect_field_name='post_detail' in my CreateView but then I get error saying there's no get_absolute_url() method even when I've already added it in the model.

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.user',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    comments = models.Manager() 

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def get_absoulute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
    path('',include(blogapp.urls)),
]
```

blogapp.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    re_path(r'^post/new/',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='post_new'),
    ...    
]
```

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post
    login_url = '/login/'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail')
```

post_form.html

```
<h1>New Post</h1>
<form class ='post-form' method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-defualt">
            Save
        </button>
</form>
```

On hitting save button in a CreatePostView it should return the PostDetailView and url should change from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/new/" to " http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1 " but I'm getting the above described error.

Answer (score 0):

Your success url should have a pk
reverse('post_detail', args=(post.pk,))

Comment: It is then showing a new error NameError at /post/new/ post is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in models:

```
('post_detail', args=(str(args=self.pk))
```

Or you should have to try redirect to a new page where you can create a URL to redirect to `post_details`.

Comment: or you can try to redirect to

Comment: re_path(r'^post/new/',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='post_new'),